# Creating an alias for my script thru Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, command-line-interface, alias

I was wondering if is there any way to set up an alias on user's `~/.bash_aliases` thru a Makefile.

Let's say I have a bash script called `foo.sh` which prints what you've passed to it. E.g.:

**Input**
`sh foo.sh bar`

**Output**
`bar`

Now, on my Makefile I want to have a something like:

```
install:
    @echo "alias foo=sh foo.sh $@" << ~/.bash_aliases
```

So everytime user does `make install` it will automatically have the `foo` alias available. Then, instead of doing the last input, we would have something like:

**Input**
`foo bar`

**Output**
`bar`

Does anyone know if it's possible to do such thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you want to add the same line to the user's `~/.bash_aliases` everytime they run your Makefile?

and what about users who don't use bash but another shell, like `zsh`?

and what about other users? if the admin types `make install`, they usually expect the "installation" to be available to each and every user of the system, not just themselves.

if you only care about making your script `foo.sh` available as `foo`, then you probably should install a binary called `foo`.

```
install:
    $(INSTALL) foo.sh $(bindir)/foo
```

btw, [Debian policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#s-scripts) mandates scripts to be installed without .sh extension. i think this is a hint that one generally shouldn't install with script suffixes.

Comment: Thank you, man. You're right about the use of "install" word here. All I wanted to do is to have `foo` available by default on user's cli. I'll try the approach you've mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
install:
    @echo "alias foo=foo.sh" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```